# How to make navigation bar transparent optimize press

Tags: css, wordpress, header

i am working with wordpress, using optimize press plugin. i am trying to make my the bar at the top where the navigation is white become transparent.

What i tried initially was to change the colour of the bar to transparent using

```
 .banner {
        padding: 2px 0;
    background-color: transparent;

}
```

it works but not completely, as the bar falls back to the colour of the background which is white so its not yet 100% transparent.

i am thinking of detaching the bar and placing it on the background image below its o it will be transparent over the background image.
but no idea on how to do this, can some one help.

i jst neeed to get the bar at the top to be transparent

the site in question for reference

[Ref site](http://hotelmarketinginternational.com/newhotel/)

Comment: means banner should be backside of navigation right ?

Comment: means the background should be at the back of the navigation, i think we are saying the same thing. my intention is so i can make the navigation bar transparent on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for this

```
.banner {
    padding: 2px 0;
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: wow thanks man, but how do i get it be a little bit thicker, am just askin thanks

Comment: i mean a bit visible but transparent

Comment: add the rgb background i.e background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);

Answer (score 2):

I have applied this CSS on given URL and it works.
So You have to apply CSS on banner class.

```
    .banner {
    padding: 2px 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then your nevigation bar will be black.
you can give color white to the anchor tag for nav-menu to appear as white.
In this given URL you have to apply CSS to this class

```
body .container .navigation ul li a{
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The opacity property specifies the opacity/transparency of an
  element.
- The opacity property can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0. The lower value, the more transparent

For example : You can try this

```
.banner {
        padding: 2px 0;
        opacity: 0.6;

}
```

Comment: it dosent work as planned, if u try it via inspecting element on the site i gave ull see wat am saying thanks